# iOS 9: “unexpected use of reserved word ‘let’ in strict mode” + “Can’t find variable: fetch”. Transpiling issues? How to fix?

Tags: ios, vuejs2, babeljs, transpiler, vue-cli-3

Using VueCli 3 "from the box", I found, that my code does not work on my iPad 2 (iOS 9.3) and using iOS 9.3 emulator I got the next errors:

1) "unexpected use of reserved word 'let' in strict mode". For a test purpose I found, which external component produces this error and temporary removed it, but then I got another error...

2) "Can't find variable: fetch". I found that `fetch` is used by apollo-link.

It seems, that for some reason my project can not be transpiled, however it looks like I tried everything what is mentioned [on this doc page](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html).

What I tried to do in order to transpile the project somehow:

1) I added `iOS >= 9.3` to `.browserlistrc` -> nothing changed;

2) Added `import '@babel/polyfill'` to `main.js` and

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@vue/app', { useBuiltIns: "entry" }]
  ]
}
```

to `babel.config.js` -> nothing changed;

3) Tried to turn on/off `modern mode` -> nothing changed;

4) Tried to add

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  transpileDependencies: ['vue-apollo']
}
```

to `vue.config.js` -> nothing changed.

Just in case, my `dependencies`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
  "register-service-worker": "^1.5.2",
  "vue": "^2.5.17",
  "vue-apollo": "^3.0.0-beta.11",
  "vue-awesome-swiper": "^3.1.3",
  "vue-draggable-resizable": "git+https://github.com/mauricius/vue-draggable-resizable.git#develop",
  "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
  "vue-youtube": "^1.3.0",
  "vuedraggable": "^2.17.0",
  "vuex": "^3.0.1",
  "vuex-persistedstate": "^2.5.4"
},
```

So nothing helped -> still have problem with iOS 9.3. My project uses PWA/ServiceWorker, which iOS 9 does not support, but I do not think that SW has any relation to this problem, as it simply should not be registered / should be ignored by iOS 9.

I found, that iOS 9 does not support neither [let](https://caniuse.com/#search=let) nor [fetch](https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch), but as I understand, vue-cli should handle it based on my settings. Did I miss any settings?

So, what should I do in order to let the project work on iOS 9?

**EDIT:**

1) `let` is from `vue-draggable-resizable`, which I temporary removed.

2) `fetch` I fixed by adding `import 'whatwg-fetch'` to `main.js`

Now I see the next problem:
`Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode`.

As I see from the 3rd example from [the Babel home page](https://babeljs.io/), Babel supports `const` and it must be transpiled, but in the compiled `chunk-vendors.xyz.js` file, which produces all the errors mentioned above, now I see 507 `const`'s. It seems like `build` ignores Babel.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked all my dependencies one by one -> just commented one by one imported components in `main.js` and `App.vue` changed to:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    TEST
  </div>
</template>
```

The result is:

1) `boostrap-vue` produces `const` problems

2) `vue-draggable-resizable` produces `let` problems.

3) `apollo-link` produces `fetch` problems.

So, in my case I was needed to add `import 'whatwg-fetch'` to `main.js` and

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  transpileDependencies: ['bootstrap-vue', 'vue-draggable-resizable']
}
```

to `vue.config.js`.